# The dimension of the operator if the domain has dimension 2

Tags: analysis

Suppose $A$ is a linear operator s.t. $A\colon X\rightarrow Y$. If $\dim(X)=2$, what is $\dim(A(X))$?

Comment: A linear operator is defined as having the same domain and codomain.  So $Y=X$ (in other words $A$ is an endomorphism from a module to itself).  However $A(X)$ is the image of $A$ not the codomain, so it could potentially be a subspace of $X$ with a smaller dimension.  So without any more information I'd say that $\operatorname{dim}A(X) \le 2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necessarily, $\mathrm{dim}(A(X)) \leq 2$. If you choose a basis $\{e_{1}, e_{2}\}$ for $X$, then by linearity of $A$ we have that $A(X) = \mathrm{span}\{Ae_{1}, Ae_{2}\}$, which would have dimension $2$ precisely when $Ae_{1}$ and $Ae_{2}$ are independent.